# Whole Ubuntu System Freezes

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, freeze, crash, browser

When I try to resize my browsers (chrome and firefox) by holding and dragging around the corners for few seconds (3-5), the whole system freezes and I have to forcefully shutdown my laptop with the power key. My laptop is intel based i7 10th gen and I am running Ubuntu 20.4 (updated to latest version). And my laptop does have graphics card (RTX 2060).
I work as a frontend developer so this problem has been bugging me very much. Please, let me know what sort of problem am I facing and its possible solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: By using the power button, are you saying the text terminals cannot be used, and SysRq commands direct to the kernel aren't working either?  You've tagged crash, so was there some clues to the crash found in `/var/crash/`?   (freezes don't leave trails usually, but crashes do).  You've tagged Lubuntu which implies to me LXQt, but you say Ubuntu throughout (which implies GNOME?)

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?